# Pass connection string to ViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to follow best practices for MVVM (as I understand them).  I have a solution with Views in my main project and ViewModels in another.  I have a static class in my main project that returns a connection string for the current environment based on a command-line argument (e.g., /env=Production or /env=Development).

I want to inject the connection string into the ViewModel via XAML.  The following works, but it requires me to hard-code the connection string in the XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ObjectType="vm:SchedulerViewModel">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <sys:String>Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = MyDb_Dev; Integrated Security = true;</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Is there a way to replace the hard-coded string `Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = MyDb_Dev; Integrated Security = true;` with a call to a public property in my static class (named Global): `Global.CnString`?  Or am I fundamentally "doing it wrong"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me, with the caveat that the static class `Global` is defined in a namespace that the XAML calls `local`.

```
<ObjectDataProvider 
    ObjectType="vm:SchedulerViewModel"
    >
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <x:Static Member="local:Global.CnString" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

This viewmodel constructor is called:

```
public SchedulerViewModel(string connString)
{
    ConnectionString = connString;
}
```

Comment: So simple.  I was getting hung up because I was leaving the `<sys:string></sys:string>` tags in place and wrapping them around the `<x:Static Member="local:Global:CnString" />` tag.  Thanks, Ed.